# Why should we load translation using http in react-i18

Tags: reactjs, rails-i18n, i18next

I was going through [React-i18](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks) instructions and they have shared [this snippet](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks#configure-i-18-next)

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
// not like to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide 
// for passing in lng and translations on init

i18n
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

From the code snippet, it says

```
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
```

What is the advantage of loading json over http? Can't we just import json instead of making http request?

Answer (score 3):

Importing JSON file would mean you already have the complete file in your app (with all the translations) [BUILDTIME]. Requesting for an external file gives you the opportunity to update that file with new keys or modify the existing ones [RUNTIME]

Modifying the file you would want to import inside ts/js file requires rebuilding of your entire app

Comment: so are you saying that the only difference is that I can change json data anytime and i won't have to compile if go for http request? or did I missed something?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am thinking

Answer (score 0):

Besides what @user0101 said, you can lazy load the translations only for necessary pages. It can also be done via chunking but it is more difficult than just getting translations from backend.